# Using Office365 for user authetication and give access to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have a website. We usually use Microsoft forefront for asking the user for its username and password to log in. Recently, we have a requirement to allow users to use Office365 to log in to our website. So we have to integrate Office365 into our website to allows a user to login into our website using Office365. So I am trying to use Microsoft.Graph. I have registered my app as web and got the client ID and well as a secret key. I am using this information to make a call to Microsoft Graph.

I have tried to call API as shown below. My first request(`request1`) is successful by second request (`request2`) throws an error saying its a bad request

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." System.Net.WebException**

```
var request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?client_id=myclientidvalue&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost:36541/");
var response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();            
var responseString = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
var postData = "client_id=myclientid";
postData += "&scope=http://localhost:36541/.default";
postData += "&client_secret=mysecretkey";
postData += "&grant_type=client_credentials";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request2.Method = "POST";
request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request2.ContentLength = data.Length;
request1.Host = "login.microsoftonline.com";
using (var stream = request2.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
var responseString1 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Is you application written in ASP.Net MVC? You can definitely use Organizational Logins without having to write low level web API calls

Comment: Application is not in asp.net mvc but  in asp.net. Front end is written in backbone.js with marionette framework.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You are saying that I don’t have to call low level api to integrate office365 users to my website

Comment: You probably do need to call it in this way if it isn’t MVC

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid do you know where can i find a good resource to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Is there a body in the response with more info? Are you populating parameters such as tenantid and client secret in the call?

Comment: If this is sample code can you link to the sample?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i do populate the clientid and secret but not the tenantid. Where can i get the tenantid from?

Comment: Let’s both google it and see who gets the answer first. Tenantid is a large GUID representing your tenant

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/find-your-office-365-tenant-id

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I was googling it, one guy has used clientid as tenantid, but it didn’t work some guys.

Comment: The tenantid in your URL is definitely not clientid. Its definitely tenantid. Although the doco is very confusing on the subject.

Comment: Yup, it is very confusing

Comment: Anyway pop your tenantid in there and see if you can inspect the return body for more information

Comment: Have you read this? There's a a whole host of parameters that you need to populate in that code. Wherever you got the code from... you should read the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to verify the user with their Office 365 account? Or do you want to get data from the OneDrive?

Comment: @Stephan I just wanna verify user through Office365 account for our in house website. People will use office365 login credentials to login into our in house website

Comment: @Jay If the only thing you want to accomplish is having them login with their Office 365 account. You'll need to have a look at the OpenID Connect flow, but forefront isn't an options because it will interfere with the login.

Comment: Have you tried using the MSAL .js libraries rather than hand roll this ?